# How to add condition on select2 remove button

Tags: jquery-select2

[image]

I need to add condition upon click on the remove button, how can i add a script?

Comment: no one can answer my question or is it irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',
    allowClear: true
});

https://select2.org/selections

Title --> Clearable selections
```